# how I convert into string?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I select field in database using sql command

```
 partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner'). browse (cr, uid, ids, *args)
                partner_name = partner_obj.ids
                customer = (partner_name)
                cr.execute("select b.city from res_partner a, res_partner_address b where b.partner_id = a.id AND a.id = %s",(customer))
                ads = cr.fetchone()
                city = ads and ads[0] or None
```

but, I just know we must convert into string. I already try to make like this (the code above), but still doesn't work.

I made like this, because you want to know SO is in a message in which the city

may you help me, please

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to run raw SQL, you should be able to use the browse records to get the information you want. I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted from your question, but I'll assume that you are passing in a list of partner ids, and you want back a list of all the city names that they have addresses in. I have not tested this code, it's just a suggestion.

```
def find_cities(self, cr, uid, partner_ids, context=None):
    cities = set()
    partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    for partner in partner_obj.browse(cr, uid, partner_ids, context):
        for address in partner.address:
            if address.city:
                cities.add(address.city)
    return list(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

First point in OpenERP city is not relation field so when you will trigger sql to fetch the city you will get the name but if you have any customization which stores the city code then you need one more SQL injection to fine out the matching city from city code.

If like if you have city as relation fields with res_partner_address so in that case city field will store only id of the relation record table so when you use sql injection what you will get is id of the city which is linked to your address.

Let me know if I am missing something, Thank You.

Comment: sorry I am no to understand. please explain in simple. how if I make like this. `cr.execute('SELECT city FROM res_partner_address WHERE city = %s',(city,))
                    city = cr.fetchone() [0]` my goal, I can looke in the new from, e.g "Algolait" in cities where, Taiwan pr what ?

Comment: ok I understand a little. but until now its still an error code. why do I connect to res_partner. because I want to know, SO is a message there Algolait Algolait and in which city. it is my goal

Comment: Which OE Version you using and Do you have customized the Partner table fro City or using generic implementation from OE ?

Comment: what OE ? this, I want make relation like this.., I just look the database if I want find algolait in cities where, that's mean, first I must look **id** in res_partner and then I look at the table res_partner_address, I see **partner_id** I was looking for, and I would know his name and greet in the town where he lived